# How can this code work out in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

In linux kernel, in file arch/arm/mach-exynos/cpuidle.c, there is the following code:

```
    local_irq_disable();

    cpu_do_idle();

    local_irq_enable();
```

where cpu_do_idle is

```
    dsb         
    wfi
    mov     pc, lr
```

In cpu_do_idle, it does 'wfi' command which stands for wait for interrupt.
But, what I'm not understanding is that it enters cpu_do_idle after disabling irq.
How does this happen?

Comment: local_irq_disable() disables interrupts on that particular processor, but it doesn't stop interrupts on other processors. So cpu will come out of idle when any interrupts come on other processor.

Comment: Do you mean interrupts from other processor to this processor (like IPI)?

Comment: can you share the link of cpu_do_dle() code, after that only I can say. But I am sure it is not IPI, that is very specific concept.

Comment: I've editted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WFI` waits for the hardware interrupt, regardless the current interrupt handling state of the CPU. When CPU is woken up, it has the chance to re-enable interrupts and process any pending ones:

> WFI suspends execution until one of the following events occurs:
>
> - an IRQ interrupt, regardless of the CPSR I-bit
> - an FIQ interrupt, regardless of the CPSR F-bit
> - an Imprecise Data abort, unless masked by the CPSR A-bit
> - a Debug Entry request, regardless of whether Debug is enabled.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHEGBBF.html